# Is there a convenient way to set default matplotlib styles?

Tags: matplotlib

I use `matplotlib` a lot in my work -- to get an idea of what data I'm looking at, to make visualizations for my web site, and to put graphs in papers. It's a great tool. But I've found that the default plotting styles, while functional, can be made much more visually appealing by tweaking a few things.

For instance, whenever I create a new axis I've found that I prefer if it has particular settings for the spines, to make it look a little more Tufte-esque :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.xaxis.tick_bottom()
ax.yaxis.tick_left()
ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position(('outward', 6))
ax.spines['left'].set_position(('outward', 6))
```

This is pretty annoying to type out every time I want a new axis, so I've put it in a small module. What I'm wondering is whether there's a way to save these "settings" in matplotlib somehow ? My guess is no, but I figured I'd see if anyone has any tips.

I saw a similar question at [Creating sets of default values for Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301140/creating-sets-of-default-values-for-matplotlib), but that question was addressed towards settings that are in the matplotlibrc construct. This question is more addressed towards settings that one (apparently) has to set programmatically.

Comment: There is on-going work on making this easy: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/2236

Comment: Ah, fantastic ! Glad to see this is underway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make it a function:

```
def gimmeanaxis():
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

  ax = plt.subplot(111)
  ax.xaxis.tick_bottom()
  ax.yaxis.tick_left()
  ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
  ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
  ax.spines['bottom'].set_position(('outward', 6))
  ax.spines['left'].set_position(('outward', 6))
  return ax
```

Then you only have to type it once. Add options as you see fit (e.g. a `figure`, a subplot designation, ...)

Comment: Late update: I just ran across http://olgabot.github.io/prettyplotlib/ which is basically this, done even better. Thought I'd give it a shout-out here.