# Changing line properties in matplotlib pie chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, pie-chart

I'm trying to make the lines on my matplotlib pie chart much lighter. Because I have so many slices, the lines are way too thick, as shown here:

[image]

I read [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915871/matplotlib-controlling-pie-chart-font-color-line-width) which suggests using rcparam like this:

```
matplotlib.rcParams['text.color'] = 'r'
matplotlib.rcParams['lines.linewidth'] = 2
```

but although I can change the text color, it doesn't change the width of the lines between the pie slices. I believe that's because the slices aren't governed by line objects but by wedge objects. So is there a way to set the wedge border style and color?

Thanks a lot,
Alex

Answer (score 17, accepted):

try this:

```
ax = plt.subplot(111) 
wedges, texts = ax.pie(np.abs(np.random.randn(5)))

for w in wedges:
    w.set_linewidth(2)
    w.set_edgecolor('cyan')
```

[image: pie]

Additionally, if you only have an `axes` object and don't have direct access to the pie's wedges you can retrieve the wedges from `ax.patches`:

```
wedges = [patch for patch in ax.patches if isinstance(patch, matplotlib.patches.Wedge)]
```

Comment: You can probably also pass in `linewidth` when you call `pie`.

Comment: @tcaswell just tried that on matplotlib `1.3.1`, did not work

Comment: Yeah, that is odd/not right.  Most of the plot signatures have a `**kwarg`, but `pie` does not.  I may do something about this if I have time today.

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot. Can confirm, pie does not have a regular linewidth/color option, so have to jump through these hoops.

Comment: @tcaswell Please do! I'd love to pass linewidth in to pie…

Comment: @aclark Can you create an issue on github about this?  Otherwise I will forget again ;)

Comment: @tcaswell i added the [issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/2899) on github

Answer (score 6):

Im coming late to this party, but just found that, for pie charts, instead of using:

```
plt.rcParams['lines.linewidth'] = 2
```

you can use:

```
plt.rcParams['patch.linewidth'] = 0
```

Also, to change the pie chart line color use this:

```
plt.rcParams['patch.edgecolor'] = 'white'
```

instead of:

```
plt.rcParams['line.color'] = 'white'
```

Comment: Much more intuitive and easier than the above for basic needs, thanks.